# Why is my FinderSync extension crashing before it starts?

Tags: macos, cocoa, null, crash, findersync

I get this crash every time my FinderSync extension starts up:

```
Process:               My Finder Sync [8364]
Path:                  /Applications/Company/Container.app/Contents/PlugIns/My Finder Sync.appex/Contents/MacOS/My Finder Sync
Identifier:            com.company.Container.My-Finder-Sync
Version:               [Set on build machine] ([Set on build machine])
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           My Finder Sync [8364]
User ID:               1129915948

Date/Time:             2019-01-04 11:31:34.146 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G4015)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        013E2942-CED9-22FA-438A-E3D0BA89EB5C

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D21EDE9D-237A-412A-8456-B96453886BAD

Time Awake Since Boot: 3200 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2600 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: 37990439-1DFE-4F0B-9865-6FC1D34A3BE4)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff31eb523b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff59147c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff31ef64c4 _CFThrowFormattedException + 202
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff31db87cc -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 1020
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff3408b348 -[_NSExtensionContextVendor _setPrincipalObject:forUUID:] + 106
5   Foundation                          0x00007fff3408ab04 __105-[_NSExtensionContextVendor _beginRequestWithExtensionItems:listenerEndpoint:withContextUUID:completion:]_block_invoke + 804
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff59d2f5fa _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff59d27db8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff59d33395 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1148
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff31e6db39 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff31e2fcda __CFRunLoopRun + 2586
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff31e2f033 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff31119d96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff31119b06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff31119884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff2f3c9a73 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
16  AppKit                              0x00007fff2fb5fe34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff2f3be885 -[NSApplication run] + 764
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff2f38da72 NSApplicationMain + 804
19  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff5a0bbd77 _xpc_objc_main + 580
20  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff5a0ba9ca xpc_main + 433
21  Foundation                          0x00007fff33f825f5 +[NSXPCListener serviceListener] + 0
22  PlugInKit                           0x00007fff50ddbf8d -[PKService run] + 704
23  PlugInKit                           0x00007fff50ddbb99 +[PKService main] + 55
24  PlugInKit                           0x00007fff50ddbfb1 +[PKService _defaultRun:arguments:] + 17
25  Foundation                          0x00007fff34130229 NSExtensionMain + 51
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff59d61015 start + 1
27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff59eb1b66 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a07c080 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff59e0d1ae abort + 127
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff57d07f8f abort_message + 245
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff57d0812b default_terminate_handler() + 265
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff59149ea3 _objc_terminate() + 97
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff57d237c9 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff57d23843 std::terminate() + 51
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff59d27dcc _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff59d33395 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1148
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff31e6db39 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff31e2fcda __CFRunLoopRun + 2586
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff31e2f033 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff31119d96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff31119b06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff31119884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2f3c9a73 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2fb5fe34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2f3be885 -[NSApplication run] + 764
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2f38da72 NSApplicationMain + 804
20  libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff5a0bbd77 _xpc_objc_main + 580
21  libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff5a0ba9ca xpc_main + 433
22  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff33f825f5 -[NSXPCListener resume] + 165
23  com.apple.pluginkit.framework   0x00007fff50ddbf8d -[PKService run] + 704
24  com.apple.pluginkit.framework   0x00007fff50ddbb99 +[PKService main] + 55
25  com.apple.pluginkit.framework   0x00007fff50ddbfb1 +[PKService _defaultRun:arguments:] + 17
26  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff34130229 NSExtensionMain + 51
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff59d61015 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff59eb228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a079009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a078be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff59eb228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a079009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a078be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff59eb228a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a079009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a078be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a078bdc start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x0004000200000006 0 + 1125908496777222

Thread 5:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff59ea820a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff59ea7724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff31e30665 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff31e2f9b7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff31e2f033 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2f506fc4 _NSEventThread + 184
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a079661 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a07950d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5a078bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff927a7380  rcx: 0x00007ffee31a6c68  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffee31a6ca0  rsp: 0x00007ffee31a6c68
   r8: 0x00007ffee31a6b30   r9: 0x00007ffee31a6d00  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x0000000000000030  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x000000000000002d
  rip: 0x00007fff59eb1b66  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff92784168
```

As you can see there's only Apple platform stuff in there. Even worse, is that this happens *before* any of my code is called! At least, it never hits my breakpoint in my `FIFinderSync` class' `init`.

So what's going on here? Why is it crashing with something about a UUID key and `nil` value in some dictionary? I've gone through all my code and ensured that can't happen (I do have some dictionaries like that, but all are in Swift code and the values are not optional so can never be `nil`; nevermind that their breakpoints aren't hit either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift does some name mangling, even when it doesn't seem like it. When you do something like reference a class name via a string, like in a FinderSync extension's `info.plist`, that doesn't always work as intended in Swift.

For instance, if you have a class like:

```
@objc
class MyFinderSyncPrinicpalClass: FIFinderSync {
    // ...
}
```

try compiling that and looking at the generated Obj-C header. It probably looks something like this:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC17My_Finder_Sync10MyFinderSyncPrinicpalClass")
@interface MyFinderSyncPrinicpalClass : FIFinderSync
// ...
@end
```

This means that Swift and Objective-C code can both simply refer to it as `MyFinderSyncPrinicpalClass`, but anything that wants to refer to its compiled form via a string, such as in reflection or that `info.plist`, sees that mangled name `_TtC17My_Finder_Sync10MyFinderSyncPrinicpalClass`. To fix this, simply specify the name explicitly in the `@objc` annotation:

```
@objc(MyFinderSyncPrinicpalClass)
class MyFinderSyncPrinicpalClass: FIFinderSync {
    // ...
}
```

Now if you [compare that to the newly-generated Obj-C header](https://www.diffchecker.com/sw40G0Ud), you'll see what I mean:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("MyFinderSyncPrinicpalClass")
@interface MyFinderSyncPrinicpalClass : FIFinderSync
// ...
@end
```

Now you may refer to it by its actual name in `info.plist`, and it'll be started up as intended!

Comment: in my case that did't help. I had this crash on iOS<12.2 because my PrinicpalClass inherited from Swift class that was located in other module (framework). I tried a lot of things but no luck. So only 1 thing helped: I refactored those class in those module from swift to Obj-c and it worked :) Hope somebody will find it useful. Seems iOS <12.2 (w/o swift stdlib) cant instantiate principal class if it is inherited from swift class in other module

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! If you submit that as another answer, I'll definitely upvote it 

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that something in the Info.plist of your extension is wrong. Perhaps there's a missing value there and when the OS attempts to get its value, it gets back nil. It may then attempt to put that value into another dictionary when the exception occurs. Judging from the names of the functions involved, it might be your Principal Class or similar entry from the Info.plist file that's missing.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the correct path! Turns out since I'm using a Swift class as the principal class, there was some name mangling going on. Even though it was `@objc class MyFinderSync: FIFinderSync`, I had to change it to `@objc(FinderSync) class MyFinderSync: FIFinderSync`, and now it works! Annoying, but glad it was an easy fix. **Should I post that in a separate answer or do you wanna edit that into yours?**

Comment: Sounds like you understand the details better. Feel free to post a separate answer.